# error="insufficient_scope" when accessing yahoo Japan API order info

Tags: yahoo-api

I have a problem when using yahoo Japan API.
When using order info API, the server always returns an error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Error>
    <Message>
Please provide valid credentials. Bearer realm="yahooapis.jp", error="insufficient_scope", error_description="insufficient scope"
</Message>
</Error>
```

Here is my request:

```
https://circus.shopping.yahooapis.jp/ShoppingWebService/V1/orderInfo
Authorization: Bearer accessToken
<Req>
    <Target>
        <OrderId>orderId here</OrderId>
        <Field>PayStatus,SettleStatus</Field>
    </Target>
    <SellerId>sellerId here</SellerId>
</Req>
```

So, maybe you think my accessToken is expired or invalidate. But when I use this accessToken to access user info API, it's work, so the accessToken is not a problem.

```
https://userinfo.yahooapis.jp/yconnect/v1/attribute?schema=openid
Authorization: Bearer accessToken
```

I don't know what's wrong with my request, maybe you know. Thanks.

**Update:**
For people who have the same problem, here is my solution.
You need to contact with yahoo to ask them allow you permissions to use shopping API. That's it :))

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue so what i did while doing authorization i added scope keyword in request params and while access yahoo site it ask me to give permission for other information like email, name and etc. so its works fine after that. check params added while authorization.

```
'scope'         => $scope
```

home this will help you..